# Flatten a Curved Section of a Mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a mesh I generated by converting a beveled curve to a mesh. The result is very useful, but I would like to make one curved part of it flat. Can this be done without selecting each face and moving it?

Comment: Just a tip. You can flatten the selected vertices to a certain axis by hitting s to scale then selecting the axis then hitting 0. Scaling to zero flattens. Try it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily if you use proportional editing and scaling.

1. Turn on proportional editing:

   [image]
2. Select the top layer of vertices using box select:
   [image]
3. Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) along the Z axis (<kbd>z</kbd>) then press 0 to scale it it flat. Scroll your mouse wheel to adjust how much of the mesh it affects:
   [image]
4. And you get:
   [image]

If your curve isn't flat like in the previous example, it's still possible, it just takes a little more work.

1. Select the edge loops around the area you want to flatten (using <kbd>Alt</kbd> *Right click*):
   [image]
2. Pull them out to be flat with the middle edge loop.
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-Select the middle edge loop and push all of them in:
   [image]
4. Continue tweaking it until it's flat enough:
   [image]

Comment: Combined with Adam's comment above, this did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. Select the faces you want to flatten, then delete;
2. Select the two border lines, press <kbd>W</kbd> > **Bridge Edge Loops**, to create linked faces between them;
3. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to tweak number of cuts for the flat-curved faces.

[image]

[image]